# machine learning to parameterize a function f(x) = a*x1 + b*x2 + ... + n*xn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scipy, parameterization

First, I apologize if this question is wrong or has been asked before. I was having trouble searching for answers because parameters are a thing in machine learning but I mean a different kind of parameter, and I don't really know what to search for. I'm actually now wondering if `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` would do the job?

Here is the problem I'm trying to solve:

- I have a small training set of x and y.
- For each item in the set:

  - `x = x1, x2, x3 ... xn (floats)`
  - `y = binary true/false (binary)`

I need to create a custom function `f(x)`. Function `f(x)` is required for another piece of software, which will generate novel x. The software uses a sampling algorithm to generate `x` that lead to positive values for `f(x)`, and avoid `x` that lead to negative `f(x)`.

Suffice to say, the software will use `f(x)` to create `x`, so I'd really like it to get high positive numbers for "true" `x` and low negative numbers for "false" `x`.

`f(x) = a*x1 + b*x2 + ... + n*xn`

**Can I use machine learning to optimize parameters `(a, b, ... n)` for `f(x)?`**

`f(x)` should returnpositive value for "true" `x`, and negative value for "false" `x`.

I can do advanced python coding, I just have 0 experience with machine learning but think it might help me parameterize `f(x)`.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use logistic regression for this. The implementation of this in the scikit learn package should have everything you need.

Comment: @RajeshM thank you so much. i used scikit learn logistic regression and it worked perfectly.